# PHP echo in html title not working

Tags: php, html

This is my first PHP code, so this might be obvious.

I have this code

```
<?php $titel="Projektsida";?>
<?php include("include/config.php"); ?>
<?php include("include/header.php"); ?>
```

in a simple .php file with some other HTML code.

This is the `<titel>` code in the .php file called header.php

```
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
```

This is the error message I get when running the code through the server:

> **Notice**:  Undefined variable: title in **/home/saxon/20142/hulo14/www/htmlphp/me/include/header.php** on line **6**

I know about the misstake about load order, but I think this is fine.

I have looked at other forums and etc. for an awnser, but have not found one.

Comment: you have defined titel but echo title :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <?php $titel="Projektsida";?>
```

Should be

```
 <?php $title="Projektsida";?>
```

Comment: Yep, beeing late at night and working for 10+ hours is not helping me with my spelling... Really appriciate the help! Will accept it asap

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is the reason?

```
<?php $titel="Projektsida";?>

<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
                  $titel
```

So you should rename your variable `$titel` (or `$title` to `$titel` in `echo` part):

```
<?php $title = "Projektsida";?>
```

Comment: Why downvote? Is something bad in this explanation???